# If $\{x_n\}$ is positive, decreasing and $\sum x_n=\infty,$ then $\sum x_ne^{-\frac{x_{n}}{x_{n+1}}}=\infty$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence, divergent-series

The problem is

> Suppose that $\{x_n\}$ is positive, monotonic decreasing and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty x_n=+\infty$. Prove that
> $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty x_ne^{-\frac{x_{n}}{x_{n+1}}}=+\infty.$$

This is a past examination problem of *Analysis*. I tried many ways, but failed. One trival idea is to prove $\frac{x_{n}}{x_{n+1}}$ is bounded above, but I failed to show it, maybe it is not ture.  Hope to find some hints here, thanks in advance.

Comment: By ratio test, we know $\limsup \frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n}$ is not less than $1$ (decreasing conditions and positivity of infinite sum means all terms must be positive, so we can drop absolute values), so in particular the inverse quotient is not eventually greater than $1$, so $\exp(-\frac{x_{n}}{x_{n+1}} )$ is not eventually less than $1/e$ so the modified sum should eventually be roughly at least as big as $1/e$ times the original sum (and thus diverges). There's some fanagling to be done to formalize that idea, but it should suffice.

Comment: Could you give more details on what you tried?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Clearly, the sequence $\{x_n\}$ converges. If $x_n\to a>0$, then $x_n/x_{n+1}\to 1$, and hence $\mathrm{e}^{-x_n/x_{n+1}}$ is lower bounded, say by $b>0$, and hence
$$
\sum x_n \mathrm{e}^{-x_n/x_{n+1}}\ge b\sum x_n =\infty.
$$
If $x_n\to 0$, set
$$
S_k=\{n\in\mathbb N: 2^{-k}<x_n\le 2^{-k+1}\}
$$
Then
$\sum_{k=0}^\infty\sum_{n\in S_k}x_n=\infty$, and
$$
\sum_{k=0}^\infty2^{-k+1}|S_k|\ge\sum_{k=0}^\infty\sum_{n\in S_k}x_n\ge \sum_{k=0}^\infty 2^{-k}|S_k|.
$$
Therefore $$\sum_{k=0}^\infty2^{-k}|S_k|=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=0}^\infty2^{-k+1}
|S_k|=\infty.$$ Also, if $n,n+1\in S_k$, then $\mathrm{e}^{-x_n/x_{n+1}}\ge \mathrm{e}^{-2}$. Hence, if
$S_k=\{j,j+1,\ldots,\ell\}$, then
$$
\sum_{n\in S_k}x_n\mathrm{e}^{-x_n/x_{n+1}}>\sum_{n=j}^{\ell-1}
x_n\mathrm{e}^{-x_n/x_{n+1}}\ge \sum_{n=j}^{\ell-1}
x_n\mathrm{e}^{-2}\ge 2^{-k}(|S_k|-1)\mathrm{e}^{-2}.
$$
Thus
$$
\sum_{k=0}^\infty\sum_{n\in S_k}x_n\mathrm{e}^{-x_n/x_{n+1}}\ge \sum_{k=0}^\infty2^{-k}(|S_k|-1)\mathrm{e}^{-2}\ge \mathrm{e}^{-2}\sum_{k=0}^\infty 2^{-k}|S_k|-\mathrm{e}^{-2}\sum_{k=0}^\infty2^{-k}=\infty.
$$

Comment: This is a very nice answer! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 6):

(This is inspired by [Yiorgos S. Smyrlis' answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4672514/42969).)

Divide $\Bbb N$ into two complementary sets of indices
$$
 A = \{ n \in \Bbb N \mid x_{n+1} \le \frac 12 x_n \} \, , \\
 B = \{ n \in \Bbb N \mid x_{n+1} > \frac 12 x_n \} \, .
$$

If $k < l$ are two elements of $A$ then $x_l \le \frac 12 x_k$ (here we need the fact the the given sequence is decreasing). It follows that the $k$'th element of $A$ is $\le 2^{-k}x_1$. $A$ can be empty, finite, or infinite, but in any case is
$$
 \sum_{n \in A} x_n < \infty 
$$
and therefore
$$
 \sum_{n \in B} x_n = \infty \, .
$$

Then
$$
 \sum_{n=1}^\infty x_n e^{-\frac{x_{n}}{x_{n+1}}} \ge 
\sum_{n \in B} x_n e^{-\frac{x_{n}}{x_{n+1}}} \ge e^{-2} \sum_{n \in B} x_n = \infty \, .
$$

---

*Remark:* The proof shows that under the given conditions,
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty x_n f\left(\frac{x_{n}}{x_{n+1}}\right)=\infty
$$
holds for any positive, monotonic decreasing function $f:(0, \infty) \to (0, \infty)$.

Comment: (+1) This is the way I approached this. It is simple and extends well.

Comment: I had clicked, but it doesn't seem to have stuck. I tried again.